# Power series, Binomial series closed form

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series

does the power series

$\sum^l_{k=0} \left( \begin{matrix} l \\ k\end{matrix} \right)\frac{x^k}{k!}$

has a closed-form?

where $\left( \begin{matrix} l \\ k\end{matrix} \right) =\frac{l!}{k!(l-k)!}$

and $l$ is a positive integer (or zero).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Interesting. It can be approximated as $[(x+1)^l+e^x]/2$. $C(l,k)=C(l,k-1)+C(l-1,k-1)$ might be useful.

Comment: Not looking like it according to page 1 here: https://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math4160f19/notes/ch5_exponential_gfs.pdf

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^l\binom{l}{k}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

$$=\frac{(l+x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}}{x}\text{M}_{-l,\frac{1}{2}}(x)+\frac{(1-l)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}}{x}\text{M}_{1-l,\frac{1}{2}}(x)$$

$$=\ _1F_1(-l;1;-x)$$

$$=L_l(-x)$$

$\text{M}_{\kappa,\mu}$ is the [Whittaker M function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function),
$_1F_1$ is [Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function),
$L_l$ are the [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials).